# Fedora-atomic image with latest docker and kubernetes installed

Tags: docker, fedora, kubernetes

Latest fedora-atomic 24 image from fedora web-site contains docker 1.10.3 and kubernetes 1.2.0.

I'm trying to find a way to create atomic image with latest docker(1.12.1) and kubernetes (1.3.5).

As I understand, I can create package repository at https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/ and use it during image creation. But I was unable to build docker 1.12 there from source package found here: https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/docker/

Also I was unable to use package repository from official docker install guide, because package in it called **docker-engine** and I won't be able to install rpm-ostree package, because it has **docker** as dependency.

What the easiest way to build fedora-atomic image with latest docker and kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

Atomic has stayed on those versions for various reasons (mostly stability and supportability) which has been talked about on their mailing list.

To upgrade those components you will need to compile your own rpm-ostree. Atomic recently got support for [overlaying packages](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/08/new-centos-atomic-host-with-package-layering-support/) on the install but it's still in early stages.

To compile your own rpm-ostree you can start with their documentation [here](https://rpm-ostree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/compose-server/) and their blog post [here](http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/compose-your-own-tree/).

If your goal is a stateless server with minimal footprint I would also recommend looking at [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/). Their latest alpha version includes docker 1.12.1 and kubelet 1.3.5 at the time of writing this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to run a different version of Kubernetes today is to [use system containers](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2017/09/running-kubernetes-on-fedora-atomic-26/), using "atomic install".

If you want a different version of Docker, you should probably run that in a System Container as well.  Detailed documentation on overriding the default Docker is in progress.